# Difficulty (drain plumbing wise) in splitting a large bathroom on the second floor into two bathrooms?

Tags: bathroom, drain, drain-waste-vent

We have a large main bathroom and we'd like to split it so we have a small master bath and a smaller main bath. Layout wise, door wise, etc, we think it will fit but we're trying to gauge the difficulty in adding two additional drain lines and moving the existing ones to new locations. We'll have to demo the entire subfloor but after that is it usually straight forward for a plumber to run drain lines like this? The new location is within 8' of the old one so it's not that far of a span.

Edit: Image. 
Existing contains a double vanity in the larger portion with toilet and tub in smaller part.
New would remove everything except mayby the existing toilet and add single shower and vanity in small room with new tub/toilet and vanity in larger room. Closet would be removed from larger room.
[image]

Comment: This question is far too broad. Please provide photos and/or a sketch of your current plumbing so suitable answers can be given. Usually it's not a problem, but that's not helpful to you or the community since your case may not be "usual".

Comment: Just a note, drain lines under the floor are obvious for people to think about and visualize, but every drain needs some venting that runs up through the walls.  Don't forget to think about the vents.